# Why Java Stream don't get a List<> cannot be converted to boolean

Tags: java, inheritance

I have following Entity which is parent to Substance and Synonym Entity it contains a Substance Object and a List of Synonym Objects

```
public class SubstanceEntry {

    private Substance substance;
    private List<Synonym> synonymList;

    public Substance getSubstance() {
        return substance;
    }

    public void setSubstance(Substance substance) {
        this.substance = substance;
    }

    public List<Synonym> getSynonymList() {
        return synonymList;
    }

    public void setSynonymList(List<Synonym> synonymList) {
        this.synonymList = synonymList;
    }
}
```

then when I try to getSynonymList with `getSynonymList()`

```
List<SubstanceEntry> substanceStruct;
substanceStruct.add(substance);
substanceStruct.addAll(synonymList);

substanceStruct.stream()
        .filter(substanceEntry -> substanceEntry.getSynonymList()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

the compiler outputs an error it  says

> Bad Return Type in lambda expression `List<Synonym>` cannot be converted to boolean.

Why?

> Edit Now i changed filter to .map now when i try to assign it to a List variable it is also complaining see image below. Can someone explain it to me what is happening? [image]

Comment: `substanceEntry.getSynonymList()` is a `List`, not a `boolean`. What property of the list are you intending to test? Emptiness?

Comment: yeah but filter returns a stream so does .map and not a boolean so why is it expecting a boolean

Comment: Are you trying to eliminate some items from your original list, are you trying to extract all synonyms into their own list, or something else?

Comment: in regard to your update, the resulting type should be `List<List<Synonym>>` instead of `List<Synonym>` or if you actually want a `List<Synonym>` then use `substanceStruct.stream()
        .flatMap(substanceEntry -> substanceEntry.getSynonymList().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: @OusmaneD. sure a flatMap is also not working since same as above no instance of Type variable exist so that List<Synonym> conforms Stream<? extends R> ??? What does that even mean

Comment: @MicroLova it's working for me. see [**Ideone**](https://ideone.com/E3Q7ml)

Comment: @OusmaneD. ok i see i need to add an additional .stream after the getSynonmsList method. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is quite clear and meaningful.

The lambda `substanceEntry -> substanceEntry.getSynonymList()` returns  a `List<Synonym>` which does not conform with the `Predicate` that `filter` expects i.e. `Predicate<SubstanceEntry>`.

You're most likely looking for `map` or `flatMap` instead of `filter` or if you indeed require `filter` then ensure a valid `Predicate<SubstanceEntry>` is supplied i.e. a lambda that returns a *boolean*.

Comment: yeah but filter returns a stream as well as .map so WHY is  expecting a boolean?

Comment: @MicroLova what the `filter` intermediate operations returns and what it consumes (the argument) are _two different_  things. if you look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) you can see that `filter` requires a `Predicate<? super T>` which in your case is `Predicate<SubstanceEntry>`, so the function you supply must be **boolean returning**.

Comment: You *give* `filter` a thing that returns a boolean.  You *get* a stream back.